# Retrieve value of an attribute using Xpath

Tags: xpath

Given the html below I am trying to extract the value currently occupied by 'Milky Way'. Using an path query of "//a[@class='tooltip']/@title" only gets me so far though.

Using my query I'm able to get the embedded HTML. What I'm after is the value (currently Milky Way) contained within that HTML..

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<a href="#" class='tooltip' title="<div>  <p>Milky Way</p> <p></p>
<table> <colgroup> <col> <col> <col> </colgroup> 
<thead> 
<tr> <th scope='col'>Boost</th> 
<th scope='col'>&nbsp;</th> <th scope='col'>Wibble</th> </tr> 
<tbody>  
<tr> 
<td>Polo</td> 
<td>Mints</td> 
<td>Spangles</td> 
</tr>  
<tr> 
<td>Skittles</td> 
<td>Mars</td> 
<td>-Yorkie</td> 
</tr>  
</tbody> 
</table>   
</div> ">Sweeties</a>
```

Comment: Does your `title` attribute really contain a whole Html tree with `<div>` and `<p>` elements?

Comment: yes, I know it looks a bit odd :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, though Im not sure having all this unescaped markup in an attribute makes a valid html

```
//a[@class='tooltip']/@title
```

if you have control over its structure, consider escaping it or move it to a [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) block, like:

```
<![CDATA[
.....
]]>
```

Comment: it seem like you changed your question and now we have the same xpath :) what doesn't work then?

Comment: editted for clarification and the query was corrected.

I have no control of the source